# Windows 7 - how to use LAN as main connection & Wifi as secondary connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lan

Windows 7 is always switch to Wifi connection once I connected to Wireless LAN. How do I prevent that ?

How can I force LAN as primary connection while Wifi is only used as backup ?

When I move around, I'll need Wifi but when I am at my desk, I preferred LAN for faster speed. Can we make LAN connection as default ?

[image: How to use LAN as primary connection ?]

Comment: This is somewhat dependent upon your device manufacturer and drivers. There may be an option to automatically disable WiFi completely upon connection to a wired network, and re-enable it upon disconnection from the wire. Alternatively, there's probably a hot key combination (Fn key plus one of the F keys) that will easily toggle the WiFi or "Airplane Mode" on-demand. Note that setting of auto-switch may override your hot key's capability.

Comment: Depending on your device, the option to set the auto-switch may be in your BIOS/UEFI and/or in the "Advanced" tab on the Properties dialog for it in Device Manager.

Comment: Thanks for hinting to the right direction  - I knew there was an option to make LAN higher priority than Wifi. I just don't know which term to search for xD

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys for pointing to the right direction.

I have found how to make LAN the main connection while still connected to Wifi, so that we can enjoy both mobility and performance. Here are the how-to steps:

1. Click Start --> Run, type in ncpa.cpl
   It will open Network Connection control applet.
2. Click Advanced --> Advanced Settings, under Adapters and Binding tab, move your LAN connection to the top. See the explanation: connections are listed in the order which they are accessed by network services.
   [image]
   [full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyuNe.png)
3. To test it, I copy 15GB file over the network. So even though I am connected to Wifi, the copying is still using LAN bandwidth (which is way faster than Wifi). You can see the Network Utilization percentage.
   [image]
   [full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JMJU.png)

Comment: Not quite the fix I was suggesting, but that'll work too.

Comment: On Windows 10, using wifi as a backup connection to wired ethernet lan cable is different because in windows 10 Adapters and Bindings it's gone. This alternate powershell method works for me: 

`Set-NetIPInterface –InterfaceIndex <the ifIndex of the interface in output from Get-NetIPInterface> –InterfaceMetric <a number lower than the wifi InterfaceMetric>`

Set it larger than InterfaceMetric of your vpn connections, if you have any. You'll still see multicast bonjour/zeroconf announcements on the wifi but routed traffic will go through the wired cable. 

source: https://is.gd/D8baOj